# Smallest two sums of integers in array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array filled out with integers (sorted or unsorted, whichever will be easier, but in here I will make it sorted):

`10,20,20,30,40`

What I try to do is get two smallest sums of those numbers. In this case, it should be `60`, because:

`10+20+30 = 60` and `20+40 = 60`. What I tried to do is when I have sorted array, split numbers that the first goes left, second right, left, right... But I don't get smallest sum. In this case with my algorithm I would get sums of:

`10+20+40 = 70` and `20+30 = 50` which is not very effective.

Just so you know, I am working on a time management algorithm, so I want to get best-smallest times possible.

Comment: look up "knapsack problem" or "backpack problem".

Comment: Why not 10 + 20 = 30 as the smallest sum?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks man, it works! And `10+20 = 30` is smallest sum but the rest gives bigger sum which is what we do not want. Example, you and your friend deliver pizza and you wanna go for lunch ASAP together. Would you give him only `30` and you take the rest, in this case `90`?

Comment: (The problem might be rephrased _Split a set of integers in two parts with sums as close as possible_.)

Answer (score 0):

There would be N! Ways to select a group out of N numbers if there were no duplicates. Generate all possible groups. The best group has the minimum sum without being less than half the total, since the other numbers have a sum not more than half.

Comment: This is naïve, while he likely seeks an optimised solution.

Comment: @EliKorvigo OP says knapsack is too complex and you want to do what? Simulated annealing?

Comment: I don't see the OP saying, that knapsack is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closer in spirit to the bin packing problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

The greedy algorithm there works fine for your test case

First, sort your array

[40,30,20,20,10]

Initialise two empty bins

A=[] b=[]

At each step, remove the largest element from your array and put it in the bin with the smallest sum (if they have equal sum, put it in A)

For your array, this works as follows

```
step 0:
[40,30,20,20,10]
A=[] B=[]

step 1:
[30,20,20,10]
A=[40] B=[]

step 2:
[20,20,10]
A=[40] B=[30]

step 3:
[20,10]
A=[40] B=[30,20]

step 4:
[10]
A=[40,20] B=[30,20]

step 4:
[]
A=[40,20] B=[30,20,10]
```

And you have the desired answer. Of course, you can find sets for which this fails, it's an approximate algorithm. For example, [50,49,33,33,33]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve what I was looking for, and as you said, it fails for some sets which cannot happen in my program due to various sets of integers.